Resolve different subdomains for different subnets with dnsmasq
I have a dnsmasq server with DHCP and DNS enabled. It serves multiple subnets. My goal is to dynamically register connected machines from different subnets on different subdomains. All of my subnets are connected to a pfSense firewall with DHCP relay activated.
Let's say that my domain is example.com:
Expected behavior:
I need one subnet (192.168.10.0/24) to have it's clients dynamically resolved using the main domain example.com. The client with hostname client1 and IP 192.168.10.10 should be resolved with client1.example.com
Another subnet (192.168.4.0/24) needs to have it's client dynamically resolved using the subdomain sub1.example.com. The client with hostname client2 and IP 192.168.4.10 should be resolved with client2.sub1.example.com.
Current behavior:
My current configuration is resolving all clients with the main domain name example.com: client1.example.com and client2.example.com`. Here is the configuration:
#### DNS ####
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-hosts
no-resolv
expand-hosts
strict-order

addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq-hosts.conf
expand-hosts
domain=example.com
local=/example.com/

# LOG DNS
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
log-queries=extra

#### DHCP ####
log-dhcp
interface=ens18
dhcp-range=192.168.10.10,192.168.10.50,1h
dhcp-option=option:netmask,255.255.255.0
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.10.254
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.10.1
dhcp-option=option:domain-name,"example.com"

dhcp-range=set:sub1,192.168.4.10,192.168.4.50,255.255.255.0,1h
dhcp-option=tag:sub1,option:router,192.168.4.254
dhcp-option=tag:sub1,option:dns-server,192.168.10.1
dhcp-option=tag:sub1,option:domain-name,"sub1.example.com"

I feel like the domain-name option in the DHCP is only setting the default search domain and has nothing to do with the DNS registration. How can I resolve this problem?
